# Using pre-order traversal and string methods to flatten binary tree to find subtrees?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Recently, I ran into this solution for finding if a provided tree was a subtree of a bigger tree:

https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/88700/easy-o-n-java-solution-using-preorder-traversal

The solution is really intuitive and creative, so I implemented a recursive version of it for my own edification; but I found myself wondering why this same solution doesn't work with post-ordering or in-ordering.

Here's my attempt at a C++ solution that passes all of LeetCode's test cases:

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;

    void generatePreOrder(TreeNode *root, std::string &s)
    {
       if (root == 0)
       {
           s+=std::string(",#");
           return;
       }
       s+=std::string(",");
       s+=std::string(std::to_string(root->val));
       generatePreOrder(root->left, s);
       generatePreOrder(root->right, s);
    }
    bool isSubtree(TreeNode* s, TreeNode* t) {
        generatePreOrder(s, s1);
        generatePreOrder(t, s2);
        int pos = s1.find(s2);
        return (!(pos == std::string::npos));
    }
};
```

Fundamentally, it seems like we're just flattening the tree onto a string and using string comparison functions to find the similarity between the trees. So, I would imagine as long as the ordering is consistent between both trees, either of the three ordering schemes should work fine. However, when I change the solution so that it does in-order:

```
 ...
    void generateInOrder(TreeNode *root, std::string &s)
    {
       if (root == 0)
       {
           s+=std::string(",#");
           return;
       }
       generateInOrder(root->left, s);
       s+=std::string(",");
       s+=std::string(std::to_string(root->val));
       generateInOrder(root->right, s);
    }
 ...
```

The solution fails to pass all of the LeetCode cases. Is this because there's something innate about pre-ordering that this approach works? Or is it just a hole in the LeetCode exercise mechanism and the entire approach is flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every differently-shaped tree produces a unique preorder or postorder traversal when you include nulls.

That is NOT true for an inorder traversal, which would always start with null, end with null, and alternate between nulls and nodes.

E.g., these trees:

```
  B          D    
 / \        / \
A   D      B   E
   / \    / \
  C   E  A   C
```

both produce

```
,#,A,#,B,#,C,#,D,#,E,#
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you! Assuming we don't include nulls, I'm guessing we'll need to validate using BOTH an In-Order and Pre-Order string?

Comment: If you don't include nulls, then preorder, postorder, or checking with both all fail the challenge.